Some of the components of the div 'nav-bar' are being displayed outside the navbar, can anyone help me with this issue?
I was trying to create a react project on sorting visualizer,
this project includes a navbar component with various sorting algorithms and a slider to change the size of an array and an generate button to generate a random array. The JSX and the CSS files are as follows:
this is the jsx page
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import "./SortingVisualizer.css";

function SortingVisualizer() {
  let [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
  let [range, setRange] = useState(0);

  const randomIntFromInterval = (min, max) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  };
  const resetArray = () => {
    let newArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < range; i++) {
      newArray.push(randomIntFromInterval(5, 550));
    }
    setArr(newArray);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="nav-bar">
        <span className="range-value">{range}</span>
        <input
          className="range"
          type="range"
          name=""
          value={range}
          min="0"
          max="150"
          onChange={(event) => {
            setRange(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <button onClick={resetArray}>Generate</button>
        <p className='bubble-sort'>Bubble Sort</p>
        <p className='selection-sort'>Selection Sort</p>
        <p className='insertion-sort'>Insertion Sort</p>
        <p className='quick-sort'>Quick Sort</p>
        <p className='merge-sort'>Merge Sort</p>
        <p className='heap-sort'>Heap Sort</p>
      </div>
      <div className="ice-pick">
        {arr.map((num, id) => (
          <div key={id} className="element" style={{ height: `${num}px` }}>
            ‎
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SortingVisualizer;

and this is the css file for the jsx file
.ice-pick {
    text-align: center;
}

.element {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-right: 1px;
    background-color: rgb(77, 165, 184);
    top: 40px;
}

.nav-bar {
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 75%;
    height: 80px;
}

.range-value {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 110px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #999;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.range {
    width: 200px;
    height: 15px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background: #111;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  .range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #0dd69d;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 4px solid #333;
    box-shadow: -407px 0 0 400px #00e8fd;
  }

button {
    margin-left: 20px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #00e8fd;
}

button:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px #00e8fd;
}

upon running the server some of the components of the navbar that is the sorting algorithms inside the div 'nav-bar' are being displayed outside the navbar. I tried using various styling in css but couldn't fix the issue.
